# Await two Promises in feathersJS

Tags: typescript, feathersjs

```
// users.hooks.js

const userDeletion = require('../userdeletion/userDeletion');
const triggerUserDeletion = () => {
  return async (context) => {
    const userDeletionRes = userDeletion(context);
    const userDeletionResRes = userDeletionRes(context);
    await Promise.all(
      [userDeletionResRes]
    );
  };
};

// userDeletion.js

module.exports = () => {

  return async (context) => {

    const userDeletionResult = await context.app.service('replicate').remove(
      {
        // ...
      }
    );

    const userDeletionResultData = userDeletionResult.data[0];
    console.log(userDeletionResultData);

  };
};
```

Above is my hook. How can I await 2 Promises, ie to call 2 services (not only the replicate service)

Comment: You can either `await context.app.service('replicate').remove(); await context.app.service('foo').bar();` (just as you would with normal function calls), or you can `await Promise.all([context.app.service('foo').bar(), context.app.service('foo').bar()])`. The former will do this sequentially, the latter will try to resolve the Promises in parallel. You already have both ways in your code. Am I missing something?

Comment: Thanks, that is a super helpful answer. You can post as full answer and get the green checkmark. As for your question - In my above example the hooks file is requiring the js file for better seperation of concerns. I wasn't sure in which of the asyncs I should do the resolution of the additional service. As an aside I noticed it only resolves if I do the double context referencing, I wonder why I need to do that. `const userDeletionRes = userDeletion(context); const userDeletionResRes = userDeletionRes(context);`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should create both promise objects, then use `await Promise.all(promise1, promise2)` or `await Promise.allSettled(promise1, promise2)` to pause until both have received data back.

By not calling `await` on each promise individually, you allow both requests to run in parallel, speeding up the function which relies on them both. This is more pronounced the more requests you make, but even with two requests it can halve the time spent waiting.

`await Promise.all()` will wait for all promises to resolve, or *will throw an error as soon as any promise rejects*. This is useful if you need both requests to succeed in order for program execution to continue - this way you can immediately begin error handling.

`await Promise.allSettled()` will wait for all promises to resolve or reject. You can then map over the list of objects returned and check the `status` field to determine whether they resolved or rejected. This is useful in cases where you want to have more granular error handling, or can recover from a failed request and continue with function execution.